# How rotation result image(or video) when setDisplayOrientation(90)?

Tags: android

I create a camera app:

```
mCamera =Camera.open()
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

I capture image and video ok. But result not rotation 90.
How roation result of camera the same with View of Camera?
Or set result ouput the same setDisplayOrientation?

Comment: Are you showing your result in imageview ? And where do you want rotation; in camera itself or after capturing iamge ? Be more specific..!

Comment: Camera rotation ok by mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); But result of camera not rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate a image after capturing use EXIF interface in android

```
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can it rotation with video?

Comment: I want set  result of camera the same with View of Camera (image and video). Do you known?